# +2 at a rep cost

Tags: feature-request, reputation, up-votes

Sometimes I like an item so much that I would be willing to give it more exposure with extra upvotes as the expense of personal reputation points (SE currency).

Has such a feature ever been considered? If so, what subtlety or exploitation have I missed to explain why it was rejected?

Comment: I *don't* think this is a good suggestion, which is why I've downvoted the question, and upvoted @medica's answer. But it's worth pointing out that as well as offering bounties, you can also post *links* to questions and answers (and even individual *comments*) in posts of your own, where there's at least a credible link between the context where you post, and the item you'd like others to discover through your link.

Answer (score 10):

You can't +2, but you can +50 at a cost of 50 rep to yourself by [offering a bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). This appears as a "Start a bounty" button on questions you **create or edit**.

Bounties can range from +50 to +500.

Comment: I mean +2 upvotes, not rep.

Comment: Well, no you can't give 2 upvotes. The only way to give more exposure to a question and reward an answer above an upvote or acceptance is by offering a bounty.

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I've tagged it as "feature-request". I want to be able to give more upvotes.

Comment: It'd probably be worth requesting this on the main meta.StackOverflow as I don't think this is configurable per-site.

Comment: You don't need to clear things on MSO just because it has to apply network wide. Discuss things on the site it comes up on first, *then* if people in this community agree that it has merit, then we can look at raising it to a bigger audience. But we don't need to rush things to the network meta at the sound of "bigger than just us".

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand why you want (or need) more than one vote. As @Lego Stormtrooper stated, you can always raise awareness (significantly) by offering a bounty on a question you like.

If you think a question especially worthy, I've seen someone in chat (I don't go often, so I don't know how common this is) ask others to look at a good question and vote.

Rep is garnered with a number of great questions/answers, a host of good Q/A, or a flood of mediocre Q/A. The one-vote-per-person seems to be working well enough. If everyone had two votes per question, wouldn't they use them, especially to promote a question they've answered (and often elevating a fluff question)? In the end, it would all come back to everybody being equal, with two votes instead of one. And high rep would mean less than it does now.